# TYPO3 TCA Map to field other than uid

Tags: typo3

I have two tables: `tx_ext_domain_model_tol` with `adapter` field and `tx_ext_domain_model_adapter` with `uid` and `block-uid`. So, in TCA of `tx_ext_domain_model_tol`, field `adapter` points to parent table `tx_ext_domain_model_adapter`.

Would like field `adapter` pointed to parent field `tx_ext_domain_model_adapter.block_uid` instead of the default `tx_ext_domain_model_adapter.uid`.

In this TCA setup, the relation record of table adapter is returned successfully. TCA uses tx_ext_domain_model_adapter.uid to fetch the record:

```
'adapter' => [
    'exclude' => TRUE,
    'label' => 'Block Uid',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'inline',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_ext_domain_model_adapter',
    ],
],
```

However, changing the reference field to - `block_uid` (where by it should return multiple records), returns empty.

```
'adapter' => [
    'exclude' => TRUE,
    'label' => 'Block Uid',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'inline',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_ext_domain_model_adapter',
        'foreign_field' => 'block_uid',
    ],
],
```

How can one reference a different field?

Comment: Didn't understand your problem.  'foreign_field' => 'block_uid', defines, that in tx_ext_domain_model_adapter.block_uid will point to the parent record, so the field will contain the UID of der record, where "adapter" is an field of.

Comment: @JulianHofmann Exactly. I have two tables `tx_ext_domain_model_tol` with `adapter` field and `tx_ext_domain_model_adapter` with `uid` and `block-uid`. So yes, in TCA of `tx_ext_domain_model_tol`, I would like `adapter` to point to parent record `tx_ext_domain_model_adapter.block_uid`.